# Change click function to Keydown() Keycode =32

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keycode

http://jsfiddle.net/58YWM/8/ here's the original fiddle.

I don't know why but the keydown wouldn't listen and it won't execute the function.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", explode);

var contW = $('#container').width();
var contH = $('#container').height();
var explode;

$('.holder').keydown(explode=function(e) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if(keycode === 32){
        for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++){        
            var sourceX = (Math.random()*contW)%(contW>>1);
            var sourceY = (Math.random()*contH)%(contH>>1);
            var nTop = Math.floor((Math.random()*contW)%contW);
            var nLeft = Math.floor(((Math.random()*contH)%contH));
            var $child = $(this).clone();    

            $('#container').append($child);
            $child.css({ top:sourceX, left: sourceY })
            .animate({ opacity: 0.5, top: nTop+'px', left:nLeft+'px' }, 500)
            .keydown(explode);


            $(this).hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting a jQuery error in the console.

Comment: yeah, not really sure why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably more than 1 error but you put this line :

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", explode);
```

before the variable `explode` is set. Set explode before binding the event and more errors will show, you'll be able to start debuging.